# How do I make my notes appear in multiple columns in my React.js app using Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I created a React app that lets me generate notes/post-it notes to a board. Right now, when I add new notes, they appear in a single column. How do I use Bootstrap to make the notes appear in multiple columns?

Apologies if my given background info is lacking. I'm a little bit lost and am not sure what to include and not include.

In my index.js file I've added...

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

In my board component file, I currently have the following under my render function...

```
render() {
   return (
     <div className="board">
     <div className="row">
     <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg- col-xl-2">
    {this.state.notes.map(this.eachNote)}
     </div>
     </div>

     <button onClick={this.addNote.bind(null, "New Note")}
    id="addNote"> Add </button>
     </div>
   )
  }
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns. That might be what you are looking for.